# Spark Structured Streaming using spark-acid writeStream (with checkpoint) throwing org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, qubole, spark-hive, spark-checkpoint

In our Spark app, we use `Spark structured streaming`. It uses `Kafka as input stream`, & `HiveAcid as writeStream` to Hive table.
For `HiveAcid`, it is open source library called `spark acid` from `qubole`: https://github.com/qubole/spark-acid

Below is our code:

```
import za.co.absa.abris.avro.functions.from_confluent_avro
....

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("events")
  .config("spark.sql.streaming.metricsEnabled", true)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val input_stream_df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
  .option("startingOffsets", '{"events":{"0":2310384922,"1":2280420020,"2":2278027233,"3":2283047819,"4":2285647440}}')
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10000)
  .option("subscribe", "events")
  .load()

// schema registry config
val srConfig = Map(
  "schema.registry.url"           -> "http://schema-registry:8081",
  "value.schema.naming.strategy"  -> "topic.name",
  "schema.registry.topic"         -> "events",
  "value.schema.id"               -> "latest"
)

val data = input_stream_df
  .withColumn("value", from_confluent_avro(col("value"), srConfig))
  .withColumn("timestamp_s", from_unixtime($"value.timestamp" / 1000))
  .select(
    $"value.*",
    year($"timestamp_s")       as 'year,
    month($"timestamp_s")      as 'month,
    dayofmonth($"timestamp_s") as 'day
  )

// format "HiveAcid" is provided by spark-acid lib from Qubole
val output_stream_df = data.writeStream.format("HiveAcid")
  .queryName("hiveSink")
  .option("database", "default")
  .option("table", "events_sink")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/user/spark/events/checkpoint")
  .option("spark.acid.streaming.log.metadataDir", "/user/spark/events/checkpoint/spark-acid")
  .option("metastoreUri", "thrift://hive-metastore:9083")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
  .start()

output_stream_df.awaitTermination()
```

We able to deploy the app to production, & redeployed it several times (~ 10 times) without issue. Then it ran into the following error:

> Query hiveSink [id = 080a9f25-23d2-4ec8-a8c0-1634398d6d29, runId =
>   990d3bba-0f7f-4bae-9f41-b43db6d1aeb3] terminated with exception: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 42, 10.236.7.228,
>   executor 3): org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException:
>   /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/events/year=2020/month=5/day=18/delta_0020079_0020079/bucket_00003
>   for client 10.236.7.228 already exists (...)  at
>   com.qubole.shaded.orc.impl.PhysicalFsWriter.(PhysicalFsWriter.java:95)
>     at com.qubole.shaded.orc.impl.WriterImpl.(WriterImpl.java:177)
>     at
>   com.qubole.shaded.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.(WriterImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   com.qubole.shaded.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.createWriter(OrcFile.java:334)
>     at
>   com.qubole.shaded.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater.initWriter(OrcRecordUpdater.java:602)
>     at
>   com.qubole.shaded.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater.addSimpleEvent(OrcRecordUpdater.java:423)
>     at
>   com.qubole.shaded.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater.addSplitUpdateEvent(OrcRecordUpdater.java:432)
>     at
>   com.qubole.shaded.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater.insert(OrcRecordUpdater.java:484)
>     at
>   com.qubole.spark.hiveacid.writer.hive.HiveAcidFullAcidWriter.process(HiveAcidWriter.scala:295)
>     at
>   com.qubole.spark.hiveacid.writer.TableWriter$$anon$1$$anonfun$6.apply(TableWriter.scala:153)
>     at
>   com.qubole.spark.hiveacid.writer.TableWriter$$anon$1$$anonfun$6.apply(TableWriter.scala:153)
>   (...)     at
>   com.qubole.spark.hiveacid.writer.TableWriter$$anon$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:153)
>     at
>   com.qubole.spark.hiveacid.writer.TableWriter$$anon$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:139)

Each time the app is restarted, it shows different `delta + bucket files` already exists error. However, those files are newly created (most probably) each time it starts, but no clue why the error is thrown.

Any pointer will be much appreciated.

Comment: try setting the write mode to append, outputMode(OutputMode.Append)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the actual root cause from the worker's error log. It was due to code changes I made in one of the library used, that causes `out of memory` issue.

What I posted before was the error log from the driver, after several failures on the worker node.